# Remote Desktop - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up a remote connection to my home PC, but I'm not able to connect. I am able to use RD over LAN (but that's not a big success), I'm just not able to connect over internet.

INFO:

Both computers are running Windows 7 Professional

Router is Arris TG1682G (Comcast)

WHAT I DID:

1) I fixed the local IP of the host computer and forwarded port 3389 to the computer.

2) I disabled the Windows firewall for testing and checked the boxes on the host to accept Remote Desktop connections.

3) From another computer, I am able to ping the host successfully, but the connection fails when I try to telnet.

4) Using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, port 3389 using the host's public IP is open.

I set up a DDNS service. When I try using another computer to connect to either the DDNS or public IP of the host, I get an error that it can't connect.

What could I be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the other computer that you use to test the internet side? Is it actually OUTSIDE the network? Not every router supports loopback connections and if you are inside your network, trying to access the public port using your public IP, it may fail because the router gets confused.

Comment: Yes, I am testing it from a work computer that's outside of the network.

Comment: It could be something on that computer itself. I would start testing from other computers/devices to be sure. For example, your mobile phone with app, not connected to wifi. Just connect and disconnect. Your configuration sounds like its okay.

Comment: What Security option you have selected under System Properties - Remote Connection? Have you checked 'Allow Connections from Any Version of remote desktop? Also under Advanced is the option 'Allow this computer to be controlled remotely' checked?Is the account password protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, it sounds like a possible issue with the DDNS service and/or Network Level Authentication being required on your home PC. But moreover, there are some security issues with this setup. For reasons too lengthy to go into here, **TCP port 3389 should *never* be open to the outside world.** Other than for a learning experience, I can't imagine a use-case for this setup. If this is for home use, why not just use a free program like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/latest-version/?pid=google.tv.teamviewer_download_ex_sl1.s.us&gclid=Cj0KEQjw2fLGBRDopP-vg7PLgvsBEiQAUOnIXCWVwi8d5CPsYeZCyk19IOhwmgFtJdbEFP_gD0zvn2QaAvyr8P8HAQ)? It works really well, is simple to setup and use and you don't compromise security.

Comment: I had read about TeamViewer, but I was hesitant. I wanted to use Windows RD to get smooth integration and so that it would be easy for my father-in-law to remote in. Based on your comment, I tried out TeamViewer and it's great. I loaded the portable to a flash drive for easy use. Also, it has good flexibility, like letting me transfer files easily to the host computer. (Also much safer for a non-computer person like me.) Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked out! :)